# Sending Authentication between 2 separate apps

Tags: ios, uiwebview

We have 2 IOS applications, the 'master app' contains a webview where we authenticate a user via a webform. Within this app we have a button which switches to the 'child app' from the master (which is fully native) using e.g. `child://` however we wanting to know if theres a way we can send an authentication token or similar from the master app to the child one to make sure it deems it to be safe/secure.

Basically 'child app' also has authentication (via a different method to the master) if you go to that app directly but we want to bypass this if it receives a genuine request from the 'master app'.

Comment: The ways, first using keychain with share between both: http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/ saving for example the cookie, or the type of the credentials used at the second application

Answer (score 0):

The ways, first using keychain with share between both: evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios saving for example the cookie, or the type of the credentials used at the second application

(not advise) Or, you can send it direcly on the deeplink, child://tokenId, and parse it at the child:

-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
          openURL:(NSURL *)url
          sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
          annotation:(id)annotation

and parse url, In some projects I use this one to help the parse: https://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes